# How has your joint / secondary appointment in another department turned out?

Tags: joint-appointment

I am curious about the experience of faculty who hold / have held appointments in multiple departments. Has it helped you researchwise? Any unexpected challenges?

I am thinking primarily about people in research-focused universities in science and engineering, but other perspectives are most welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure why this matters. Do you have a reason for asking? Context might help.

Comment: This is in essence a shopping question, which we don't particularly like on this forum. Try asking a more specific question.

Comment: Separately: My personal take is that dual appointments are a really bad idea for pre-tenure people and a moderately bad idea for associate professors. They are a good idea for people once they have all of their promotions out of the way.